# PHP How to split a one dimensional array in two dimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a one dimensional array which looks like this:

```
$table = array("rnbqkbnr", 
               "pppppppp", 
               "00000000", 
               "00000000",
               "00000000", 
               "00000000", 
               "00000000", 
               "PPPPPPPP", 
               "RNBQKBNR" );
```

What I want to do is make that array a two dimensional, each element to be an array on it's own, so I can access every letter.

Something like this:

```
$arr= array(
    array("r", "n", "b", "q", "k", "b", "n", "r"),
    array("p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p"),
    array("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
    array("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),        
    array("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),        
    array("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
    array("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"),
    array("R", "N", "B", "Q", "K", "B", "N", "R")
);
```

I tried different finctions like str_split(), or array_chunk(), or explode(), but everytime I end up getting the first function ($table) which is one dimensional and I can't acces every element separately.

Every help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You can already access every letter.

[A string is series of characters (Php Doc)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

This work's fine.

```
print_r($table[0][0]); // return r
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) coupled with [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to arrive at a pretty easy solution to this:

```
<?php

$table = array(
   "rnbqkbnr", 
   "pppppppp", 
   "00000000", 
   "00000000",
   "00000000", 
   "00000000", 
   "00000000", 
   "PPPPPPPP", 
   "RNBQKBNR" 
);


$table = array_map('str_split', $table); // thanks @RolandStarke

var_dump($table);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each of the array in your outer array:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($table); $i++){
    $table[$i] = str_split($table[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use str_split inside a foreach loop

```
foreach($table as $key=>$line)
{
 $table[$key]=str_split($line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried but this should work:

```
foreach($table as $v)
{
    $arr[] = str_split($v);
}
unset($v);
```

Comment: why would you be looping with `$v` as a reference when not even using the reference? Just seems to me to be an unnecessary risk waiting to happen if you forget the unset. You could also just do `$v = ...` and it will overwrite the original value in the array.

Comment: Passing by reference is faster? Even if that's true, this isn't going to be the bottleneck in the program. It's better to code for readability instead of micro-optimizing like that. Passing something by reference and then not using it makes the code less readable IMO.

Comment: I show passing by reference is pretty much the same all over. https://3v4l.org/Z4Asq, both trading spaces as to which was faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following. Just split each string to characters.

```
$table = array("rnbqkbnr",
    "pppppppp",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "PPPPPPPP",
    "RNBQKBNR");

$newArray = array();
foreach ($table as $t) {
    $newArray[] = str_split($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should help fix your problem up. Also, it should work for various array sizes.

```
$table = array("rnbqkbnr",
    "pppppppp",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "00000000",
    "PPPPPPPP",
    "RNBQKBNR");

for ($i = 0; $i != count($table); ++$i) {
    if (isset($subArray)) {
        unset($subArray);
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j != strlen($table[$i]); ++$j) {
        $subArray[] = substr($table[$i], $j, 1);
    }

    $twoDimensionalArray[] = $subArray;
}

print_r($twoDimensionalArray);
```